# Is possible to store a pickle file inside a python module?

Tags: python, module, pickle, filenotfoundexception

I'm building a python module and I need to store a pickle file for making the module works offline.

My module has the following structure

[image]

In the file "macinfo.py" I use the open() function as follow, for example, to get all companies stored:

```
def all_companies() -> List[Company]:
    """
    Get all companies stored in the pickle file.

    :return: A list of Company instances
    """

    return pickle.load(open("data/companies.pickle", "rb"))
```

When I try to call the function

```
all_companies()
```

inside the file named "macinfo.py" it works but when I call the same function inside "test.py" it raises, obviously, the exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/companies.pickle'
```

How can I avoid this?

**EDIT:** I tried also to use `os.path.abspath()` but the same exception is raised.

Comment: Use an absolute path name. Relative path names use the current working directory, not the directory containing the module.

Comment: I tried to use also `os.path.abspath()` but the same exception is raised.

Comment: Because `abspath` creates an absolute path using the same combination of your working directory and the relative path. You need to know where the module is installed, not where the script is run from.

Comment: Is there no way to initialize the path inside the  `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using the special variable `__file__`.

In the file "macinfo.py" I use the following code to determinate where "companies.pickle" is stored

```
path_1 = "/".join(str(__file__).split("\\")[0:-1])
path_2 = "/data/companies.pickle"
full_path = path_1 + path_2 if path_1 else "data/companies.pickle"
```

Then I use `full_path` as follow

```
def all_companies() -> List[Company]:
    """
    Get all companies stored in the pickle file.

    :return: A list of Company instances
    """

    return pickle.load(open(full_path, "rb"))
```